# Changing color of \dir in xypic

Tags: xy-pic

I'm trying to use \dir to draw custom frames in an XYpic drawing, but have been unable to figure out how to change the color of the line drawn by each command. For instance, to draw a triangle frame, I'm using the code `\POS ="i","i"+UL;"i"+DL **\dir{-};"i"+R **\dir{-};"i"+UL **\dir{-},"i"` inside a `\begin{xy}` environment. How do I change the lines drawn the `**` commands to be some color other than black?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I get colored `\dir` by adding the color between `**` and `\dir`. See `xyrefer.pdf` for more details.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[all,color]{xy}
\UseCrayolaColors
\begin{document}
\begin{xy}
\xymatrix{
A \POS[];[d]**[VioletRed]\dir{~},
      [];[dr]**[Periwinkle]\dir{-} \\
B & C \POS[];[l]**[PineGreen]\dir{.} }
\end{xy}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! That worked exactly as I wanted. I did look at `xyrefer.pdf`, but found it pretty inscrutable, so I wasn't able to figure that out.